# How to count the unblocked buildings in stack in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, stack

Description:

> Given a series of the height of buildings, for each building, please
> calculate the number of unblocked buildings it can see ahead. We say
> that the i<sup>th</sup> building with the height h<sub>i</sub> is blocked by the j<sup>th</sup>
> building with the height h<sub>j</sub> only if i < j and h<sub>i</sub> ≤ h<sub>j</sub>. The
> unblocked building (the j<sup>th</sup> building) that the i<sup>th</sup> building it can see
> ahead satisfies: (1) j < i and (2) not blocked by any k<sup>th</sup> buildings with
> k < i.
>
> Write an algorithm that runs in O(n) total time.
>
> Sample Input:
>
> ```
> 8
> 5 3 8 3 2 5 5 5
> ```
>
> Sample Output:
>
> ```
> 0 1 2 1 2 3 2 2
> ```

> I have written the following code in C. I am not sure why am I getting the wrong answer. I tested quite a number of different cases which all give correct answers(I cannot find a wrong test maybe I am testing not a large number of buildings in the test case I use). But I am not sure why the logic is still wrong. Also, how can I make my code more cleaner? Moreover, this task make use of StackADT and I assume that you are familiar with the basic functions in this ADT. Thank you so much for your help!

Editted:

> The parameter StackADT s is simply an empty stack called s.
> While int value refers to the height of the building.
> Suppose this function DoSomething() is computing the unblocked buildings that the observer can see when the stack s and the height of the building (int value) are passed to the function.
> In sample input 1,
> 8 means there are in total of 8 buildings
> And each number follows in the array correspond to the height of each building.

```
int DoSomething(StackADT s, int value) {
    int count = 0;
    if(IsEmpty(s)){
        Push(s, value);
        return 0;
    }
    if(Top(s) > value){
        Push(s, value);
        return s->size-1;
    }
    else{
        int result = s->size;
        while(!IsEmpty(s) && Top(s) <= value){
            Pop(s);
        }
        Push(s, value);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is in `s`, what is `value`? How is it related to the input? Unless you can figure out how to provide a [mre] or something close to it, you might not have much luck here.

Comment: You say your program produced the correct result for a lot of cases.  It would be helpful, then, to present a case where it produces a wrong answer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I suspect they don't know, because an automated tester tells them it's wrong and doesn't disclose the test data.

Comment: What, *exactly*, is the provided function supposed to do?  It doesn't compute an entire solution to the problem given, so what is its role?  And how are you sure that the error is there? As was already asked, what is the significance of its parameters?

Comment: In your example is the observer is presumable situated to the right of the array `5, 3, 8, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5]` so they are only able to see the last 5 and the 8 (the "unblocked" buildings). Correct? Please clarify (with an edit) what 'it' in the first sentence refers to.

Comment: Oh! Thank you all for your constructive comments! Also, I realized that it is way more easier to understand using array and for loop (solution provided by @CarySwoveland) Thank you so much! I will post the editted code. Thanks so much everyone!

Comment: But now, a new problem emerges, for example,  the heights of the buildings are '7 2 3 4 5 6'， the sixth building should be able to see all the buildings ahead. But the algorithm above will give the result as 2 instead of 5. Because 5 is set to be highest_so_far, but in fact 6 is able to see '4, 3, 2, and 7' as well. How to change the algorithm correspondingly? I tried it but still cannot get the correct result. Thank you for your time and kind help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The question isn't very clear, but it appears that one needs to calculate the answer from each building, which is why the stack is needed.

Comment: Is [this](https://cuhk.oj.boleyn.su/problem?cid=3&pid=160) the question?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Did you mean to link to the same question?

Comment: @Unmitigated, whoops! I'm sure I've seen this question somewhere (other than here).

Comment: David, I trust my edit (the first paragraph only) meets with your approval. You previously had "...building can see ahead..." in the last sentence of that paragraph. I found that confusing and changed it to "...building it can see ahead...". Please review that and my small changes in formatting, such as changing "i-th" to "i<sup>th</sup>".

Comment: @Unmitigated Yes exactly! That's the question I am talking about

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you for your kind help! I will be aware of this kind of fomatting issue next time! Your help is really appreciated.